# What to use to quickly cut Audio/Video

Tags: software-recommendation, video-editor, sound-editor

If just need to crop Audio/Video from a longer track, what can I use? I tried OpenShot, but I find the export video slow, perhaps its compling all the "layers" into a new movie? Perhaps I just need a simple "crop" tool for audio/video will surfice?

Comment: What sort of video formats are you dealing with?  Are you looking for a GUI or a CLI solution?

Comment: Formats will be probably mp4, flv, mp3. GUI or CLI will be fine.

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video

Answer (score 251, accepted):

- Avidemux (From PPA) - http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/
- OpenShot (From PPA) - https://launchpad.net/openshot/ http://www.openshot.org/ppa/
- Pitivi (From PPA) - http://www.pitivi.org/?go=download

I was going to mention commands like ffmpeg or avconv (The new one) which can OBVIOUSLY split files into groups. For example:

**FFMPEG**

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:30:00 -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy output1.avi
ffmpeg -ss 00:30:00 -t 00:30:00 -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy output2.avi  
ffmpeg -ss 01:00:00 -t 00:30:00 -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy output3.avi
```

Or

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 100 -i source.m4v -vcodec copy -acodec copy part1.m4v
ffmpeg -ss 100 -t 100 -i source.m4v -vcodec copy -acodec copy part2.m4v  
ffmpeg -ss 200 -t 100 -i source.m4v -vcodec copy -acodec copy part3.m4v  
ffmpeg -ss 300 -t 100 -i source.m4v -vcodec copy -acodec copy part4.m4v
```

**AVCONV**

```
avconv -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:30:00 output1.avi
avconv -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:30:00 -t 00:30:00 output2.avi  
avconv -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 01:00:00 -t 00:30:00 output3.avi
```

Or

```
avconv -ss 0 -i source.m4v -t 100 -vcodec copy -acodec copy part1.m4v
avconv -ss 100 -i source.m4v -t 100 -vcodec copy -acodec copy part2.m4v
avconv -ss 200 -i source.m4v -t 100 -vcodec copy -acodec copy part3.m4v  
avconv -ss 300 -i source.m4v -t 100 -vcodec copy -acodec copy part4.m4v
```

Or do some script like here: http://icephoenix.us/notes-for-myself/auto-splitting-video-file-in-equal-chunks-with-ffmpeg-and-python/

Comment: Beware: According to the man page [ http://linux.die.net/man/1/ffmpeg ] this results in unnatural, overlapping cuts. For instance, the second command starts at 00:30:00 but goes on for an hour; i.e., up to 01:30:00, so the third command, which starts at 01:00:00, will yield an overlapping cut. It may be the goal, but it wouldn't be very natural.

Comment: I can vouch for what ezequiel mentions. When doing the tests with ffmpeg or avconv the overlapping effect appears if using the times as mentioned above. I will update to a more accurate effect although I should mention that the first second will also overlap. I will fix both and add avconv to the group. Thanks ezequiel.

Comment: Thanks!  But these ppa versions are out-of-date.  Are the versions in Precise 12.04 good?  Or can someone suggest better ones?

Comment: Thanks for notifying me. When I get back home I'll post an updated link.

Comment: Thanks!  avconv is blazingly fast and clear and convenient for splitting out clips if you know what start/stop times you want.  No need to figure out which OpenShot video format your source file corresponds to, which I still don't know for sure....

Comment: Be careful with copy on video codec; you might get an intro without video until the next keyframe.

Comment: I would say not possible to @user165448 until that actually happened to me. I had to do a lot of research into the why it happens. It is rare BUT possible. So listen to him.

Comment: Great! avconv is so so fast. I tried in Ubuntu 15.10. I ran the avconv command but it seemed that ffmpeg ran and not avconv! What's the fact? Also please suggest me a CLI tool for combining laterally (side by side) parts of audio / video! Thanks in advance. Also hereby addressing @
Philippe Gachoud

Comment: At least when using avconv you don't need to invoke the video and audio codec separately. You should just go with $ avcon -i input-file -codec copy [any option like -ss -t -fs ... just check on ubuntu.manpages.com for avconv] output-file

Comment: you can also `sudo apt-get install openshot`

Comment: for `avconv`, adding `-map 0` will copy all streams.

Comment: @ezequiel-garzon you can force keyframes to fix this. See [How to extract time-accurate video segments with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420296/how-to-extract-time-accurate-video-segments-with-ffmpeg).

Comment: `-t` didn't work for me I used `-to` instead: `ffmpeg -ss 00:02:19 -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -to 00:00:44 output.avi` where the `-to` argument is the duration of the extract

Comment: `-codec copy` worked on mkv using ffmpeg. Example can be shown here: https://superuser.com/a/743085/71560

Comment: This answer is useful as well https://askubuntu.com/a/59388/578917

Comment: The trouble with these video editors is that they will change the resolution of your video by default.

Answer (score 41):

With new version from ubuntu avconv

```
avconv -i srcFileName -c:a copy -c:v copy -ss 00:03:40 -t 00:01:12 targetFileName
```

- First argument time is **from** time
- Second argument is **duration** (not end time) duration may be either in seconds or in "hh:mm:ss[.xxx]" form.

To specify end time instead, use the option -to [end time].

Please refer to [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) for more informations

Comment: Thanks, an expert. Damn me not to read *third*-rated answer in the thread before doing anything. Without this examples Ī̲’d fail to turn off video recoding (“-vn” failed to produce this effect, for some reason) and would also have other problems. By the way, does “-c:s copy” make the same thing for subtitles?

Comment: Also, since my experience, when cutting out only the last part (i.e. when beginning of the new video coincides with beginning of the original video) “-ss 0” is potentially problematical and should be omitted. Ī̲ had a program (namely, Bombono DVD) crashed trying to read a file made with “-ss 0” substituted in place of the original file.

Comment: Thanks Philippe! This helped me a lot. can I ask what the args `-c:a copy -c:v copy` mean?

Comment: @Alex c=codec a=audio v=video

Comment: Aha and `copy`?

Comment: @Alex copy to copy the audio codec and video codec to the target stream. See more @ https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options and refer to the ffmpeg documentation for more informations

Comment: I'm not sure this answer still works. It seems like there is no `avconv` in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. I *suspect* `ffmpeg` is the replacement, but that also doesn't work: if the cut times are not aligned with a key frame, there may be some weird things happening at the start/stop of the video.

Comment: @MRule see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/what-are-the-differences-and-similarities-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv

Answer (score 40):

[kdenlive](http://kdenlive.org) is (in my experience) the easiest software which will allow you to perform that task in a few steps and without problems. Even so, the [OpenShot Video Editor](http://www.openshotvideo.com/) project is also useful but it yet needs lots of hard work to get closer to the kdenlive.

Here are a screenshot of the kdenlive and openshot respectively:

[image]

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Kdenlive is my favourite. All other linux editors crashed when using MOV files from my Kodak Zi8 camera. Easy to use and very powerful.

Comment: Not sure what's going on with my edit.  Looks fine in editing mode but here its messed up.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand. Do you mind giving further details? If you think necessary please open a question about your issues. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry about the OT intrusion and thanks for your cordiality, I'll take it where appropriate.  Good day!

Comment: The *easiest software* Kdenlive asks a hell of irrelevant questions before even starting a project. But when about to do something, it spawns `avconv` and whenever it fails, Kdenlive won't offer help tp rectify situation and even doesn't report with which exactly parameters it ran `avconv`. Definitely a non-choice for one willing simply to trim a video file.

Comment: Personally, kdenlive seemed good, but the interface is very unintuitive and unnecessarily complex. Also, there seems to be some bug. After loading a clip, sometimes the clip plays. Sometimes it doesn't. Not recommended.

Comment: kdenlive not available for debian stable

Comment: `kdenlive` started from asking utterly pointless questions and later crashed before opening the first video files. CLI editing of video files is better than that.

Comment: `kdenlive` might seem overqualified for some of these tasks, I agree, same as photoshop might seem overqualified to crop a picture. Still, if you're comfortable with kdenlive, it works for simple stuff also. And if you try to mix and match 20 clips into one large one with transitions, well, good luck using `avconf`

Comment: Answer with snapshot to show the feature should be the accepted one in my view. Thanks for great detail sharing @GeppettvsD'Constanzo

Answer (score 32):

[LosslessCut](https://mifi.no/losslesscut/) is focused entirely on clipping/cutting, is simple to use and does not re-encode, meaning exporting is fast.

[image: Screenshot of LosslessCut]

To ensure audio remains synced with image, use [the keyframe cut option](https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut/issues/75#issuecomment-419737312).

[Github repo](https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut).

Comment: Available on the Snap Store :)

Comment: Oftentimes the initial few frames of the next merged clip would be glitchy in the final exported video

Comment: @Harsha, I'm not sure if it's relevant to that issue, but are you using the keyframe cut option?

Comment: Simple and extremely fast (3h video -> 2h in a ubuntu virtual machine in under 10 seconds!).

Comment: this is the fastest one because it will not render the video, but it is no accurate

Answer (score 25):

I like kdenlive for finishing up as well or clipping out small chunks...but if he wants to split a LARGE lecture into smaller pieces he could try:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:30 out1.mpg -ss 00:00:35 -t 00:00:30 out2.mpg
```

discussion of the command is here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=480343

Comment: you can use winff (GUI for ffmpeg) also

Answer (score 10):

OpenShot Video Editor looks promising. Have you checked it?. Checkout the features: http://www.openshot.org/features/

The official installation method is via AppImage available at https://www.openshot.org/download/

To install it just open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonoomph/openshot-edge
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openshot openshot-doc
```

Just give a try.
[image]

Comment: If he is using maverick it is in the repository

Comment: Openshot FTW! :)

Comment: If the OP only wants to quickly crop video, then AVIDemux is far easier to use than OpenShot. I've just tried them both - OpenShot was surprisingly cumbers at just letting me define the in and out points for one video track.

Comment: OpenShot is definitely more user friendly than any of the other highly upvoted answers here.

Comment: OpenShot is mentioned in the question as program that failed but for me it was acceptable (export is slow but at least it had working preview of position where I cut and was not crashing - unlike other solutions that I tried).

Answer (score 9):

I'm using ffmpeg CLI interface for that. It's very easy and fast:

- to cut video:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i InputFile -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:01:32 OutPutFile
  ```
- to cut audio:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i InputFile  -vn -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:01:32 OutPutFile
  ```

In both of these `-ss` is the start point, while `-t` is the duration of the piece.

You can calculate duration e.g. using LibreOffice Calc or python's `dateutil` package, or you can use the `-to` option which accepts the end time directly.

Comment: This answer is so helpful as well
https://askubuntu.com/a/59388/578917

Answer (score 7):

My preference for easy video clipping has always been **avidemux**.
[image: Avudemux logo]

Just set the video and audio encoding to *Copy* and choose the container format you want, within reason.

Installation:

[entry at apps.ubuntu.com](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/avidemux) [image: Install avidemux]

```
sudo apt-get install avidemux
```

Answer (score 4):

Try Avidemux (Ubuntu 14.04 and earlier).

```
sudo apt-get install avidemux
```

or [LiVES](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lives&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)

```
sudo apt install lives
```

Comment: Avidemux freezed several times for my under Ubuntu 13.10, even with a x4 CPU.

Answer (score 4):

There is also [WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/) that is avconv graphic interface. It works great. I installed it from Ubuntu Software Center.

Here is the screenshot:
[image: WinFF]

Answer (score 2):

For cutting, merging, scaling etc one can use … Blender (yes, this 3D editor, but it has also video editing part). You need workout some 20-min tutorial to survive the interface, but then it appears to be unexpectedly pleasant to use.

Answer (score 1):

I use Kdenlive, but I wouldn't be surprised if you could even slice video this way in PiTiVi:

1. Create a new project with your full lecture.
2. Set your start and end points for the first "manageable chunk" in the clip monitor.
3. Drag from the video in the clip monitor down to your timeline. It will be just the chunk you chose.
4. Set new start and end points in the clip monitor and repeat as needed.

Comment: I've looked around, and I can't find any way to divide a long clip into multiple shorter clips that I can easily manage. There is no "clip monitor"; PiTiVi is very simple (and I mean that in a good way!) Obviously, I could just cut up the video and reorganize the unnamed chunks in the timeline, but I'd like to know if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

In PiTiVi 0.13.5 (Ubuntu 10.10) I was able to simply select a clip and go to Timeline > Split (or just press "S").

Answer (score 1):

For quickly cutting I have used MythTV. I recorded some show, let it automatically search for the commercial breaks and fine-tuned the found markers. After this I started the Myth archiving function and burned all to DVD, without the commercials.

I have to admit, it worked gread from about 2006 or such. Somewhere in 2008 or 2009 some update ruined it all, my markers where somehow shifted.

Right now, I'm in the progress of re-installing this myth stuff, just to see if I can get the trimmer/editor and archiver working.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I just found that I can do it online,
With a youtube account:) If you are in a hurry, and do not have
enough time to try which ubuntu software works for you,
then do it online.

Go to youtube account, upload your video, then
select
Video Manager,
there is a Enhancement option,
at the bottom right corner there lies Trim option

[Watch this **1 minute** tutorial if you still can not find it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubHWeJ50_L4)

[image: Screen Capture of the Trim menu]

Comment: Uploading 2 GB video to get 50% back? Is it feasible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a GUI application you can use [**dmMediaConverter**](http://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html), a ffmpeg frontend, which has a **split** function, without reencoding, **fast**. Just add the split points and press Run. Also, it can do a lot of other stuff.
http://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html
[image: Split function example]

Comment: Sadly not open-source, though.

Comment: Yes, but it is free.

Answer (score 1):

vidcutter is a very useful tool for cutting, trimming and merging videos in ubuntu:

Install vidcutter:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ozmartian/apps
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vidcutter
```

works in ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](https://github.com/kanehekili/VideoCut)

[image]

I've written it to cut out ads from recorded TV videos. Using the included remuxer you do not even to have to recode it. There is nothing fancy about it. Just fast.

Answer (score 1):

### To just crop without trans-coding

(copying instead), I suggest a yad script to be run from a desktop file launcher.

I have found the script [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186595/341192).

I have modified it a bit to include video formats and to avoid transcoding.

It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=$(yad --width=600 --height=400 --file-selection --file-filter='*.mp3 *.mp4 *.avi *.m4a *.ogg *.flac *.aac *.opus')

eval $(yad --width=400 --form --field=start --field=end --field=output:SFL "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "${INPUT/%.*}-out.${INPUT##*.}" | awk -F'|' '{printf "START=%s\nEND=%s\nOUTPUT=\"%s\"\n", $1, $2, $3}')
[[ -z $START || -z $END || -z $OUTPUT ]] && exit 1

DIFF=$(($(date +%s --date="$END")-$(date +%s --date="$START")))
OFFSET=""$(($DIFF / 3600)):$(($DIFF / 60 % 60)):$(($DIFF % 60))

ffmpeg -ss "$START" -t "$OFFSET" -i "$INPUT" -c copy -map 0 "$OUTPUT"
```

So, install `yad`, save the script as `cut_audio-video.sh` and make it executable.

Than create the file `~/.local/share/applications/cut-audio-video.desktop` similar to:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Cut audio & video
Exec=/PATH/TO/cut_audio-video.sh
Icon=/SOME/AUDIO/ICON/Audio-icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;HardwareSettings;X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;System;
```

Change `Exec` and `Icon` lines.

Then it can be run with an app launcher like Synapse:

[image]

Select the file, then enter the time for start and end of the cut/crop

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a helper for ffmpeg that mimics [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) syntax.

### Usage

`ffslice infile [start [duration [outfile [ffmpeg-args]]]]`

### Examples

```sh
# Get the last 5 minutes of an MP3
ffslice input.mp3 -5:00

# Get the first 30 seconds of a webm
ffslice input.webm 0 30

# Get 5 minutes of video starting at 2 minutes in
ffslice input.mp4 2:00 5:00
```

### Code

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# substr() for MPEG-encoded files

infile="$1"; shift
start="$1"; shift
end="$1"; shift
outfile="$1"; shift
args=()

# Convert time to seconds
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412868/bash-reverse-an-array
timetosec() {
  rev="$(<<< "$1" tr ':' '\n' | sed 's/^0\+\([0-9]+\)/$1/' | tac | tr '\n' ' ')"
  IFS=' ' read -a times <<< "$rev"
  let secs="${times[0]:-0} + (${times[1]:-0} * 60) + (${times[2]:-0} * 3600)"
  printf '%i' "$secs"
}

# Input file requred
if [ -z "$infile" ]; then
  echo "Usage: $(basename -- "$0") infile [start [end [outfile [ffmpeg-args]]]]" >&2
  echo "Example: $(basename -- "$0") input.mp3 -5:00" >&2
  exit 1
fi

# Start (negative starts from the end)
if [ "${start:0:1}" = "-" ]; then args+=('-sseof' "$start")
elif [ -n "$start" ]; then args+=('-ss' "$start")
fi

# Input
args+=('-i' "$infile")

# End (use + or - to specify relative to the starting point)
if [ "${end:0:1}" = "+" ]; then args+=('-to' "$end")
elif [ "${end:0:1}" = "-" ]; then args+=('-sseof' "$end")
elif [ -n "$end" ]; then
  let dur="$(timetosec "$end") - $(timetosec "$start")"
  args+=('-to' "$dur")
fi

# Default output filename
filename=$(basename -- "$infile")
extension="${filename##*.}"
filename="${filename%.*}"
defaultOutfile="${filename}-${start}-${end}.${extension}"
if [ -z "$outfile" ]; then
  outfile="$defaultOutfile"
elif [ -d "$outfile" ]; then
  outfile="${outfile}/${defaultOutfile}"
fi

# Cannot have colon in the filename with ffmpeg
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412519/ffmpeg-protocol-not-found-for-normal-file-name
outfile="$(printf '%s' "$outfile" | sed 's/:/./g')"

# Slice audio
ffmpeg "${args[@]}" -c copy "$@" "$outfile" 1>&2

# Output the final location
printf '%s' "$(readlink -f "$outfile")"
```

### Caveat

Note that ffmpeg will only split on keyframes. This usually works well enough for most cases, but if you need precise video segments, see [How to extract time-accurate video segments with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420296/how-to-extract-time-accurate-video-segments-with-ffmpeg). You can force all the needed keyframes before segmenting.

Answer (score -1):

I always use Kdenlive.
Just import the video, drag it onto the timeline, click on the spot where you want to split it, right-click it, and choose cut. Then remove the part you don't need.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestion, but for what I need they are too complex. Note that I didn't say too difficult to use, just unnecessarily bloated for my purposes. I ended up using openshot

Comment: @jfoucher: you should accept Geppettvs's answer then ;)

Answer (score -1):

I've struggled with this same issue, having a large video file that I want to cut and save as separate scenes.  After trying to do this in the usual suspects all listed by others here I ended up using [**Kino**](http://www.kinodv.org).

You will have to import the file as Kino needs it in dv format (whatever that is) and you can then specify start and end point for each clip on the Edit tab, then export each clip individually on the Export tab.  Works great and is fast, the slowest part is the initial import of the video file.  You can even add effects like titles to each clip.

I found that it is hard to find the exact spot to cut the scene in Kino and when I play the vid in the built in player there is no sound (there is when exported) and it plays too fast so I play the video in avidemux, find the time or frame number where I want to cut it, then use this info in Kino.

I do find it crashes a fair bit (I use Ubuntu 15.04 Kino v1.3.4) but it will recover where you were upon restart.

---

Update on the [Kino webpage](http://www.kinodv.org):

> **Kino is a dead project**
>   ( 05.08.2013 14:15 )
>   Kino has not been actively maintained since 2009. We encourage you to try other Linux video editors such as Shotcut, Kdenlive, Flowblade, OpenShot, PiTiVi, LiVES, and LightWorks.