# Extract part of a video with a one-line command

Tags: command-line, video, extract

If I have a video, normally avi, but could be any, and I want to create another one in the same format but just a part, the position *i* seconds to *f* seconds into the video, what is the one-line command to do this?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

This can be done using `mencoder` or `ffmpeg`.

### mencoder

Say that you want to cut out a part starting at 00:00:30 into the original file with a 5 seconds length and that it shouldn't be reencoded (if you want to re-encode it you'll have to replace `copy` with audio and video codecs, for a list of available audio codecs issue `mencoder -oac help`, for a list of available video codecs issue `mencoder -ovc help`), then you issue:

```
mencoder -ss 00:30:00 -endpos 00:00:05 -oac pcm -ovc copy originalfile -o newfile
```

You'll have to replace `orginalfile` and `newfile` with actual file names, the latter is the name of the file that is created to hold the cut-out part.

### ffmpeg

Say that you want to cut out a part starting at 00:00:30 into the original file with a 5 seconds length and that it shouldn't be re-encoded (if you want to re-encode it you'll have to replace `copy` with audio and video codecs, for a list of available codecs issue `ffmpeg -formats -E`), then you issue:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30 -i orginalfile -t 00:00:05 -vcodec copy -acodec copy newfile
```

You'll have to replace `orginalfile` and `newfile` with actual file names, the later is the name of the file that is created to hold the cut out part.

---

<sub>For reference see http://lazyxiong-tech.blogspot.com/2007/05/using-mencoder-to-cut-out-pieces-of.html and "7. Copy Only A Part Of Video" in http://segfault.in/2010/10/ffmpeg-tricks-you-should-know-about/</sub>

Comment: I tried it and failed. Can you show me what the command would be for you with your typical codecs to use for avi, flv and mpg? I listed the codecs but couldn't make much sense of it.

Comment: @strapakowsky It depends on the input file and what codecs you have installed. Maybe you should make a new question for that and add information about what file you've got and what command you tried.

Comment: @strapakowsky I cannot get it to work with ffmpeg either but all the guides on cutting out parts with ffmpeg suggests that it should work somehow so I keep it in my answer. However, I've also added a mencoder line which I get to work.

Comment: Just used a version of this. It's not working for you because `-ss ... -t ...` needs to be *before* the `-i infile` option. See [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video) for the real one-liner. You almost got it, just not the order...

Comment: @Hendy Edited accordingly

Comment: Not true. `-t` flag must be *after* the `-i` option. Source: http://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video

Comment: also works with `avconv`   the  -t option is not necessary if you want the start point to end of video

Comment: Note that mecoder will produce an avi container by default, which may confuse your decoder if the payload doesn't normally appear in an avi container. You may be able to select a libavformat container instead (see the manual). Issues can also arise with various weird formats that mplayer is tolerant of. I suggest you test your videos with something dumb like iTunes, Windows Media Player, etc, before distributing.

Comment: Did not produce a correct clip using `mplayer-2:1.2.1-1ubuntu1.1`, but ffmpeg-7:2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 worked like a charm: thanks!

Comment: It needed to add the extension for example
```ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30 -i orginalfile.mp4 -t 00:00:05 -vcodec copy -acodec copy newfile.mp4```

Answer (score 45):

Do you need to cut video with re-encoding or without re-encoding mode?
You can try to following below command.

Synopsis:
ffmpeg -i [input_file] -ss [start_seconds] -t [duration_seconds] [output_file]

**use FFmpeg cut mp4 video without re-encoding**

```
Example:
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:10 -c copy cut_video.mp4
```

**use FFmpeg cut mp4 video with re-encoding**

```
Example:
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:10 -async 1 -strict -2 cut_video.mp4
```

If you want to cut off section from the beginning, simply drop `-t 00:00:10` from the command

Comment: Something to consider: "Using -ss as input option together with -c:v copy might not be accurate since ffmpeg is forced to only use/split on i-frames. Though it will—if possible—adjust the start time of the stream to a negative value to compensate for that. Basically, if you specify "second 157" and there is no key frame until second 159, it will include two seconds of audio (with no video) at the start, then will start from the first key frame. So be careful when splitting and doing codec copy." https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking I got more accurate cutting by leaving out `-c copy`

Comment: Why is `-async 1 -strict -2` required? Seems to work fine without them. Is this tweet relevant? https://twitter.com/ffmpeg/status/943266612047577089

Comment: What does "cut" mean? Cutting and leaving a "hole" in the original file or simply copying a section from the original file?

Answer (score 0):

**medipack** is a very simple command-line app as a wrapper over `ffmpeg`.

you can achieve trimming your video using these commands:

```
medipack trim input.mp4 -s 01:04 -e 14:08 -o output.mp4
medipack trim input.mp4 -s 01:04 -t 13:04 -o output.mp4
```

you can view options of trim subcommand as:

```
srb@srb-pc:$ medipack trim -h
usage: medipack trim [-h] [-s START] [-e END | -t TIME] [-o OUTPUT] [inp]

positional arguments:
  inp                   input video file ex: input.mp4

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -s START, --start START
                        start time for cuting in format hh:mm:ss or mm:ss
  -e END, --end END     end time for cuting in format hh:mm:ss or mm:ss
  -t TIME, --time TIME  clip duration in format hh:mm:ss or mm:ss
  -o OUTPUT, --output OUTPUT
```

you could also explore other options using `medipack -h`

```
srb@srb-pc:$ medipack --help
usage: medipack.py [-h] [-v] {trim,crop,resize,extract} ...

positional arguments:
  {trim,crop,resize,extract}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --version         Display version number
```

you may visit https://github.com/srbcheema1/medipack and checkout examples in README.

Answer (score -1):

To be more precise you can:
MANUALLY
Open the file in a media player that will frame by frame advance (potplayer my favorite but MPC-HC works)and play an AVISynth file with data such as:

```
DirectShowSource(("C:\Downloads\Video\Do you want him.flv"), Pixel_Type="yuy2").Crop(0,0,-0,-0)
Subtitle("C:\Downloads\Video\Do you want him.flv", font="Arial", size=24, text_color=$ff0000, align=3)
ShowFrameNumber(scroll=true, x=336, y=27, font="Arial", size=24, text_color=$ff0000)

ShowTime(x=398, y=44, font="Arial", size=24, text_color=$ff0000)
```

Then cut with the EXACT time format:

```
ffmpeg -i "Path\do you want him.flv" -ss 00:00:05.240 -to 00:00:08.360 -vcodec libx264 -acodec libvo_aacenc "Path\Do you want him1.flv"
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i "Path\do you want him.flv" -ss 00:00:10.240 -to 00:00:14.360 -vcodec libx264 -acodec libvo_aacenc "Path\Do you want him2.flv"
```

If you wish to join, make a txt file with the video files with contents like:

```
file 'C:\Downloads\Video\Do you want him1.flv'

file 'C:\Downloads\Video\Do you want him2.flv'
```

Run `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i FileList.txt -c copy "Path\NewName_joined.flv"
```

PROGRAMMATICALLY
I wrote a program but have no level 10 to show it, sorry