# ffmpeg-video trim from the end of the video

Tags: scripts, ffmpeg, video-editor

I have some videos of different duration.I want to cut(remove) the last 5 seconds of all videos.Can i use 'ffmpeg' in a loop to trim the videos?please help me.

Comment: edit the question by using [software recommendation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation) tag

Answer (score 2):

This will get you the duration of your file in seconds:

```
let A=$(avprobe input.webm 2>&1 | grep "^ *Duration: " | sed "s/^ *Duration: \\([0-9:]*\\).*/(((\\1)/" | sed "s/0\\([0-9]\\)/\\1/g" | sed "s/:/)*60+/g")
```

Although `avprobe` does return the fractions of the seconds, bash doesn't deal with fractions. So i'm just dropping everythinging that is less than 1 second.

After that you can easily do something like this:

```
let A=$A-5
avconv -i input.webm -t $A -c:v copy -c:a copy output.webm
```

Sorry for not using `ffmpeg`. I've switched to `avconv` a while ago, i believe that the options should be the same, and if not, it should be trivial to rewrite them as needed.

After this the question is only in wrapping the whole thing in the for loop and doing all the files at once.

Comment: FYI, for my version of `avconv` (0.8.6-1 (Debian Squeeze)), I needed to, in the final command shown above, change the beginning string of said command to `avconv -i input.webm`.

Comment: @v010dya What does `let` do? What is a `*.webm`?

Comment: @v010dya `bash: let: A=: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=")`