# How can I remove segment from a video using avconv?

Tags: avconv

How can I remove one, or multiple segments from a webm video using `avconv`
(without reencoding)?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a more elegant solution, but you could [create clips of wanted video individually using time splicing](http://askubuntu.com/a/399028/13247).

Comment: Note:  You will probably need to re-encode, but at a lossless rate.  (See [P-Frames and B-Frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types))

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Do you want to make a new video out of the webm video, without the removed segments? If yes, you can use the command above for the parts you want to KEEP, then concatenate those parts.

Comment: yes, i want to make video without removed segments.

Answer (score 2):

To remove a *single* segment of a webm file you can use the standard method of seeking to a particular section of your file and then specifying a time duration to extract.

For example the following will take a section from 1 minute into a file and copy 60 seconds following this into another file:

```
avconv -ss 00:01:00 -i video.webm -t 60 -c copy cut.webm
```

To extract *multiple* segments of a webm file you can use avconv's [basic stream segmenter](https://libav.org/avconv.html#segment). For example the following will split a webm video into 60 second segments and generate a playlist file as well:

```
avconv -i test.webm -c copy \
       -f segment -segment_time 60 -segment_list list.pls \
       output%03d.webm
```

A few choices to make with the segmenter but the above examples covers the basics...

Comment: Good answer. I tested it with segment_time = 10 sec and a 1:04 long file.  A roughly one minute long file seems was split into seven files. The time stamps were a bit strange in VLC. Each file was reported at the added time length of all the files before, including the file itself. However each file played at a shorter time, and the whole playtime added up to 1:04, same as the original file.