# How to automatically segment video using ffmpeg without re-encoding?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, convert

I have a 2 hour video. I want to make 30 minute sections but avoid re-encoding. So 2 hours of video into four 30 minute videos. How can I do this using a single `ffmpeg` command?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.

Comment: Do you mean you wanna split your 2-hour video in 30-min pieces, so you will have 4 pieces with 30-min each?

Comment: Yes. How to ? Please I ask for  command

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/56022/what-to-use-to-quickly-cut-audio-video.

Comment: What is this purpose?

-acodec copy -ss 00:30:00 -t 00:30:00 output2.avi

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -f segment -segment_time 1800 -reset_timestamps 1 output_%03d.mp4
```

- In this example output files will be named `output_000.mp4`, `output_001.mp4`, etc.
- Segments may not be exactly 30 minutes long because it must cut on keyframes only.

Comment: You can also format the arguments for `-segment_time` in hours, minutes, and seconds (eg. `01:00:00`)