# Use mkvtoolnix to split video file such that each file in same duration?

Tags: video, mkv

I search and find the way of using mkvtoolnix to split video file such that each file has same size at [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/697074), but not find the way such that each file has a same duration (like 10 minutes). Is there any way? My question is about mkvtoolnix, not about using another tools. I searched, and find some other ways with ffmpeg:

- [How to automatically segment video using ffmpeg without re-encoding?](https://askubuntu.com/a/948449/893666)
- [Splitting an MP4 file](https://askubuntu.com/a/35645)

Comment: to split by size (3GB parts):
mkvmerge --split size:3G file_name.mkv -o part_prefix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done quite easily with mkvmerge using a *simple* variation of the `--split` option:

```
mkvmerge --split duration:00:10:00.000 input_file.mkv -o split.mkv
```

This unadorned command line (other much more *complex* options are available for `--split`) will produce an out file naming pattern of split-001.mkv, split-002.mkv, split-003.mkv etc.

The full man page entry for *time / duration splitting* with mkvmerge is as follows:

```
2. Splitting after a duration.

  Syntax: --split [duration:]HH:MM:SS.nnnnnnnnn|ds
  Examples: --split duration:00:60:00.000 or --split 3600s

  The parameter must either have the form HH:MM:SS.nnnnnnnnn for
  specifying the duration in up to nano-second precision or be a
  number d followed by the letter 's' for the duration in
  seconds.  HH is the number of hours, MM the number of minutes,
  SS the number of seconds and nnnnnnnnn the number of
  nanoseconds. Both the number of hours and the number of
  nanoseconds can be omitted. There can be up to nine digits
  after the decimal point. After the duration of the contents in
  the current output has reached this limit a new output file
  will be started.
```

How cool is the command line :)