# saving the first and second 2 minutes of a wmv video in Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor

How can I cut the first two min of a 10 min video and save it as first_2min.wmv and then the second 2 min saved as second_2min.wmv without any change to the settings of the video in Ubuntu command line? The original format of the video is wmv as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to use to quickly cut Audio/Video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56022/what-to-use-to-quickly-cut-audio-video)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `ffmpeg` to rip the first 2 minutes, etc that you want.

```
ffmpeg -i 10minvideo.wmv -ss 0 -t 120 first2min.wmv
```

Then for the next 2 minutes it would be the same but change the `-ss 0` to `-ss 120`:

```
ffmpeg -i 10minvideowmv -ss 120 -t 120 second2min.wmv
```

Just remember to set `-ss` to whatever starting seconds position you want and the `-t` is the amount of time you are recording from it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: the second one should be 121 then?

Comment: @MonaJalal It can be either.  You can test the end of the first and the beginning of the second one.

Comment: Also add `-c copy` before the output file name to do a stream copy, avoiding a potentially lossy reencode (although your cuts may not be as precise)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it with a GUI:

Use [VideoCut](https://github.com/kanehekili/VideoCut), it is based on ffmpeg and OpenCV. Goal of this app was to eliminate the ffmpeg commandline:

[image: 1]

By default is does not re-encode. Your choice is to use the optimized "remux" muxer or the original ffmpeg code